# Can Quillen-Lichtenbaum recover Borel's computation?

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, motivic-cohomology

[Borel](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=ASENS_1974_4_7_2_235_0) famously used analysis on symmetric spaces to compute the rationalised algebraic $K$-theory groups of rings of integers  $\mathcal{O}_F$ in number fields, e.g. $K_i(\mathbb{Z}) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ vanishes unless $i=5,9,13,\ldots$ in which case it is $\mathbb{Q}$. Nowadays we can also access the algebraic $K$-theory groups of $\mathcal{O}_F$ using the [Quillen-Lichtenbaum conjecture](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-3-540-27855-9_5), and I am wondering whether this might give an analysis-free computation of these algebraic $K$-theory groups.

> Does the proof of the Quillen-Lichtenbaum conjecture require Borel's computation as input?

If it does not, the following question makes sense:

> Can we use Quillen-Lichtenbaum to recover Borel's computation? If not, what can it prove about the algebraic $K$-theory groups of $\mathcal{O}_F$ if we are not allowed to use Borel's computation?

Comment: The Quillen-Lichtenbaum Conjecture is a conjecture. Which proof are you referring to?

Comment: @AlexB does not it follow from Bloch-Kato conjecture, which is proved?

Comment: I am very sorry, I shouldn't comment when I am this tired. I was thinking of the Lichtenbaum conjecture on special values of zeta functions in terms of K-groups.

Comment: A citation from the K-theory Handbook (see the link in the question), page 359. " If one had finite generation results for motivic cohomology, Conjecture 1 would follow from all this work." Finite generation is a difficult question.